# Total Redirection in Page Tab Authentication

Tags: facebook, authentication, redirect, tabs

I'm building a Page Tab application that will allow Facebook users to make purchases through our client's FB page directly. In order to do that, once the user arrives at checkout, it must be authenticated and the user must be logged in in order to obtain their e-mail address.

However, when I try to authenticate the user via the URL:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT&scope=manage_pages%2Cemail

Instead of staying within the iframe, it redirects the entire Facebook page, making it impossible to easily authenticate the customer and continue on to checkout.

I'm referencing a similar app that does exactly what I need, but they seem to be using FBML which, to my knowledge, is being deprecated in 2012. If using this URL is an incorrect way to authenticate a customer in a Page Tab app, what would be the proper way to do this without the use of FBML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using authentication dialog via that URL? How about using javascript SDK function, FB.login() instead?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/